# Vue updating the value after a page refresh

Tags: vuejs2, vue-directives

```
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex class="hidden-sm-and-down" md4>
    <v-subheader class="fields">Select Venue</v-subheader>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs12 md8>
    <v-select class="select__box" :items="venues" v-model="venue" item-text="name" item-value="_id" label="Select Venue" prepend-icon="edit_location" autocomplete :error-messages="venueErrors" @blur="delayTouch($v.venue,200)" @input="delayTouch($v.venue,200)"></v-select>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>


created: async function() {
  try {
    let response = await CommonRequest.getVenues();
    let array = response.data.venues;
    let i = 0;
    for (let ven of array) {
      this.venues[i] = Object.assign({}, this.venues, {
        name: ven.name,
        _id: ven._id
      });
      i++;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
  }
}
```

here venues list id getting updated only after I refresh my page.Even the data is arrived before (as I did console.log(this.venues) to check whether data is arrived or not)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), direct assignment of array elements isn't reactive.

```
  this.venues[i] = Object.assign({}, this.venues, {
    name: ven.name,
    _id: ven._id
  });
```

Instead you can do

```
  this.$set(this.venues, i, Object.assign({}, this.venues[i], {
    name: ven.name,
    _id: ven._id
  }));
```

Note that your original code is also missing the index in the second parameter to `Object.assign`

Comment: `
created: async function() {
    try {
      let response = await CommonRequest.getVenues();
      let array = response.data.venues;
      let i = 0;
      for (let ven of array) {
        this.$set(
          this.venues,
          i,
          Object.assign({}, this.venues[i], {
            name: ven.name,
            _id: ven._id
          })
        );
        i++;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) console.log(error);
    }
  }
`
still not working

Comment: i have setted venues:[] in data

Comment: is this the tick problem(vue async updating DOM) but if it is shouldn't it automatically update the content when update patch is called?